# Member variable becomes null, spuriously?

Tags: grails, groovy

I observe an assertion failure which I've attempted to sketch below. Briefly, an initialized class member becomes null *spuriously* when I call an overridden method.

```
abstract class A<T> {
    T target

    def something() {
        assert target != null     // sanity check -- fails when invoked below
        return this
    }
}

class B extends A<Something> {
    static B makeB() {
        def b = new B()
        b.target = new Something();
        assert b.target != null
        return b
    }
}

// package test
// Test code
//
def b = B.makeB()       // <-- success.
assert b != null
assert b.target != null
b.something()           // <-- fails assertion
print "Success!"
```

I'm having trouble producing a minimal test case -- the above (with Long in place of *Something*) runs successfully at compileonline.com *but not with our code on our machines*.

*The problem goes away if I re-implement the `something` method in the subclass B.*

Has anybody observed a similar effect? I'm already quite frustrated at this.

Comment: Where is the class for `Something`? Can you add that too?

Comment: It happens to be a Grails domain object -- this is the point where I don't understand the minimal failing test case. Perhaps relevant: A is extended with both Something and SomethingElse (extends Something).

Comment: In fact I replaced `Something` with `Long` in my code and the same failure occurs. Still haven't found an independently-failing test case.

Comment: Well, what groovy version are you using (above code also works for me in 2.3.7 using `class Something{}`)

Comment: Good question: Groovy 2.1.9 (under Grails 2.3.2) -- same trouble, can't figure out the minimal test case. :(

Comment: I discovered that if `something` is overridden in class B (copy-paste, no calls to super.something), the problem disappears.

Comment: what about changing `target` to something else for testing (something really unique), which would rule out something overwriting it by accident.

Comment: Try adding a setter for the property with a println and/or stacktrace, might give some insight: `void setTarget(T t) { println "set target to '$t'"; grails.util.GrailsUtil.deepSanitize(new Exception("Don't null me bro!")).printStackTrace(); this.target = t }`

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Found: A Mixin uses the same member name

Stepping through the code and examining local stack variables carefully, we found that **the [Grails Integration Test Mixin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/mixin/integration/IntegrationTestMixin.html) has an instance variable `target` that was receiving the assignment messages.** Presumably, any instance variable sharing a name with a mixin's instance variable should be subject to the behavior I describe above, but we don't know the complete set of conditions

The most reasonably solution time-wise (with a nod @cfrick) was to rename our variable `target` to something else.

## Follow-up Questions

1. Is this expected behavior? Best solution in a sea of bad ones?
2. Has this behavior changed with a new Groovy compiler or Grails stack?
3. (still relevant) What is the minimal test case?